# TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL and TLS protocol

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

I have a Windows desktop application developed in XE2 that pulls data from a remote server in JSON format. I use Indy 10 to manage this.

The application was working fine until I received an email from the server provider people:

*"...the only protocol for securing the communication will be TLS 1.2. Older versions (TLS.1.0, TLS.1.1 or SSLv3) will no longer work."* 
They advise using TLS 1.2 or superior.

Since then I have the following runtime error

> First chance exception at $7518845D. Exception class
>   EIdOSSLUnderlyingCryptoError with message 'Error connecting with SSL.
>   Error connecting with SSL. error:1408F10B:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number'.

I found out the error is triggered when I call FidHTTP.Post (FidHTTP is an instance of TidHTTP).

I have amended the method that creates the classes in the following way:

```
constructor TMyClass.Create;

begin
  FidHTTP := TidHTTP.Create(nil);
  FidHTTP.HTTPOptions := FidHTTP.HTTPOptions - [hoForceEncodeParams];
  FidHTTP.Intercept := TIdLogFile.Create(FidHTTP);

  TIdLogFile(FidHTTP.Intercept).Filename := 'c:\'+s+'.log';
  TIdLogFile(FidHTTP.Intercept).Active := true;
  {$IFDEF VER230}
  FIdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
  FIdSSL.SSLOptions.Method:=sslvTLSv1; // I have added this line
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

but now I have another error:

> First chance exception at $7518845D. Exception class EIdSocketError
>   with message 'Socket Error # 10054 Connection reset by peer.'.

I have googled this but I have found information regarding FTP only, which is not my case.

What am I doing wrong? Is it because I have an old version of Indy without sslvTLSv1_2 option or?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sslvTLSv1` is for TLS v1.0 only.  To use TLS v1.2, you need to use `sslvTLSv1_2` instead:

```
FIdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
```

Or:

```
FIdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
```

If your version of Indy does not have `sslvTLSv1_2` then you will have to upgrade.  The current version of Indy is v10.6.2.5494.

Also, make sure you are using at least OpenSSL v1.0.1, which is the version that first added support for TLS v1.2.  The latest version of OpenSSL that Indy 10 supports is v1.0.2.

Also, you need to remove the `{$IFDEF VER230}` from your code.  That is limiting your code to creating the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` only when compiling for XE2 specifically.  By default, `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` enables TLS v1.0 only, so you will have to change the code to always create the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` unconditionally in order to enable TLS v1.2 regardless of the compiler version used (at least until [this ticket](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/181) is implemented).

Comment: I was looking at the Indy page of how to update and in the notes I can see:
"Delete all of the existing binaries - IndySystemX0.*, (dcl)IndyCoreX0.*, and (dcl)IndyProtocolsX0.*"
Does it mean I have to delete all files IndySystem??0.* dclIndyCore??0.* and dclIndyProtocols??0.*

"Be sure to check for files in the IDE's \bin, \lib, and \source folders, \Indy subfolders, and OS system folders."
What does this mean exactly? Where should I check in the IDE ?

Comment: In the end I figured it out myself. For everybody's reference, for XE2:
- IndySystemX0.* stands for IndySystem160
- (dcl)IndyProtocolsX0.* stands for IndyProtocols160.* and (dcl)IndyProtocols160.* 
- (dcl)IndyCoreX0.* stands for IndyCore160.* and dclIndyCore160.*